# How to use Kotlin-written MailChimp wrapper in Java Project

Tags: java, dependencies, mailchimp, kotlin

I'm using [MaleOrang](https://github.com/Ecwid/maleorang), a java wrapper for [MailChimp](https://mailchimp.com), which is one of the more popular email marketing sites. I added the MaleOrang jar file to my project's classpath and used the following example to connect to MailChimp and add a subscriber to my account:

```
public void RunMailChimp() throws Exception {
        MailchimpClient client = new MailchimpClient(apiKey);
        try {
            EditMemberMethod.CreateOrUpdate method = new EditMemberMethod.CreateOrUpdate(listId, Email);
            method.status = "subscribed";
            method.merge_fields = new MailchimpObject();
            method.merge_fields.mapping.put("FNAME", firstName);
            method.merge_fields.mapping.put("LNAME", lastName);

            MemberInfo member = client.execute(method);
            System.err.println("The user has been successfully subscribed: " + member);
        } finally {
            client.close();
        }
    }
```

The following error popped up though. The guy behind MaleOrang says his wrapper is written in Kotlin language, which I have no experience with, but am assuming this error has to do with that. Can anyone provide insight into how this works?

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: kotlin/jvm/internal/Intrinsics
    at com.ecwid.maleorang.MailchimpClient.<init>(MailchimpClient.kt)
    ...
```

Comment: dowload `kotlin-runtime.jar`

Comment: see https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-kotlin-jvm-internal-reflection/287

Comment: I do like the easy fixes. Thanks, that got rid of the exception, but now there's another: `NoClassDefFoundError: kotlin/text/Charsets`. The Kotlin literature seems to be well-hidden. Do you know where this dependency might be?

Comment: @corpico, you want [the Central Repository](https://search.maven.org). Search for `fc:kotlin.text.Charsets` (full classname). In this case, it isn't *on* Central, which ought to be filed as a bug against Kotlin itself.

Comment: Awesome! I was able to track it down. For anyone searching in the future, it's under stdlib: [Central Repository](https://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Ca%3A%22kotlin-stdlib%22)

Comment: You should absolutely not use classpath as a way to add dependancies! This is a Maven's or Gradle's job, not yours

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you got the whole thing the wrong way around.

A java lib is NOT supposed to be downloaded as a `.jar`. Instead, one **must** use build and dependancy management tools for that.

As the README mentions, MaleOrang is accessible though [MavenCentral](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22com.ecwid%22%20AND%20a%3A%22maleorang%22).

Add Maven or Gradle to your project, then add `com.ecwid:maleorang:3.0-0.9.2` in the configuration file as a dependency.

That way you'll be able to use any Java lib in a heart bit without warring about it dependancies (which may change over time).

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit. Sorry, I've never used Maven before and am trying to learn. I just have a normal Java project in Netbeans and have always just added Jar files to use 3rd-party libraries. Is there no way (or is the wrong way) to package up MaleOrang and all its dependencies so my project can use it?

Comment: there sure is a way to package all in one, but it is used for distribution in special cases, not for working around NetBeans

Comment: My point is that you are trying to swing agains the flow, and thus hit the rocks nobody else does. Make your life easier ;)

Comment: If you are a newbie, from my experience: 1) forget about NetBeans 2) instal InteliJ Idea CE 3) use its package manager in project settings to import libs from Maven Central 4) never manually download a jar again. This will set you up for playing around and simple projects

Comment: If I do want to, not distribute this, but use it all packaged up and self-contained on a flash drive independent of the IDE, is there a way to do that? I'm following your lead, making a project with the MaleOrang pom, but when I _Build with Dependencies_, an empty jar is spit out with the warning: `JAR will be empty - no content was marked for inclusion!`

Comment: make sure your directory structure is *exactly* as it is supposed to be. Feel free to google Maven questions like that one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19606739/maven-jar-will-be-empty-no-content-was-marked-for-inclusion