# maven build - IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, build, executable-jar

I am trying to create a jar in IntelliJ through maven clean-compile-package. Build is sucessful but I am not getting class and packages in tha jar. Please help!           I got below warning in logs:

> [WARNING] JAR will be empty - no content was marked for inclusion!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Maven: JAR will be empty - no content was marked for inclusion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19606739/maven-jar-will-be-empty-no-content-was-marked-for-inclusion)

Comment: can you brief me possible duplicate of maven mean ?

Comment: @ Sakshi your question was already answered. Click on the link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maven project have default standard directory layout its documented [here](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html)
if you not followed them or moved folders around, maybe changed output folder or similar action was taken, maven can't correctly decide how to include your class files.